# Assign And Weak

Tags: ios, objective-c, assign, weak

I want to look a difference between assign and weak.So I run this code below:

```
@interface Test : NSObject

@property(nonatomic, strong) NSString *str;
@property(nonatomic, assign) NSString *assignString;
@property(nonatomic, weak)   NSString *weakString;

@end

@implementation Test

- (id)init
{
    self =[super init];
    if (self)
    {
        self.str = @"i'm test string";
        
        self.assignString = self.str;
        self.weakString = self.str;

        self.str = nil;
        
        NSLog(@"dealloc \nstr = %p\n assignstr = %p\n weakStr = %p\n", self.str, self.assignString, self.weakString);

        NSLog(@"str = %@ \nassignStr = %@\n weakString = %@\n", self.str, self.assignString, self.weakString);
    }
    
    return self;
}

@end
```

I think it should output like this:

> str = 0x0
>
> assignString = 0x0
>
> weakString = 0x0
>
> str = (null)
>
> assignString = (null)
>
> weakString = (null)

But I get this output:

> 2015-06-17 11:22:04.676 AssignWeakDiff[4696:1897735]
>
> str = 0x0
>
> assignstr = 0x100002078
>
> weakStr = 0x100002078
>
> str = (null)
>
> assignStr = i'm test string
>
> weakString = i'm test string

It's there something wrong with my code?

Comment: Try exploring with something other than literal strings, you have no control over their lifetime.

Comment: A simple change to bypass the string literal is `self.str = [@"hello" mutableCopy]`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1. As CRD said, strings have all sorts of optimizations that alter their memory management. Repeat this exercise with your own custom `NSObject` subclass and you should see traditional object lifecycle behaviors.
2. Your expected output for the `assign` property is incorrect. You should expect that to have a dangling pointer to the deallocated object. The `assign` reference is not set to `nil` automatically when the object is deallocated. The `weak` reference will, but the `assign` reference will not.

Thus, if you have properties like so:

```
@property (nonatomic, strong) MyObject *strongObj;
@property (nonatomic, assign) MyObject *assignObj;
@property (nonatomic, weak)   MyObject *weakObj;
```

And then do:

```
self.strongObj = [[MyObject alloc] init];
self.assignObj = self.strongObj;
self.weakObj   = self.strongObj;

NSLog(@"%@ %@ %@", self.strongObj, self.assignObj, self.weakObj);

self.strongObj = nil;

NSLog(@"%@ %@ %@", self.strongObj, self.assignObj, self.weakObj);
```

At the second `NSLog` statement, the `strong` and `weak` references will be `nil`, but the `assign` reference will not.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, I also repeat this exercise with NSArray, and the console output the same result as NSString. Ok , I will try it with my custom class. thank you very much!!

Comment: @chengwen.Y By the way, make sure you use the `alloc`/`init` pattern (which will not create `autorelease` object) not the convenience factory methods. If you used array and instantiated it with a convenience method, you might have ended up with `autorelease` object, that might not be deallocated until the pool is drained.